# C# Multi line text box error

Tags: c#

i have created an application, there i have try to save the data from multiline text box to data base. But it will shown a error like 
**"String or binary data would be truncated.The statement has been terminated."**
why it will come, what should i do for store data from multiline textbox.

this is the code i have given for store the data for multiline textbox.

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spec", TextBox3.Text);
```

Comment: If you're using something like SQL that typically means that your SQL data type in the table is varchar(X), but you're trying to insert/update something with more than X characters.  If you want to save that much text, then you have to change your table schema.  If you can't do that, then you need to truncate your text to whatever X is prior to calling whatever updates the database.

Comment: check the column you are inserting the text into for the Varchar length. Probably the characters is more than specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would happen because the Varchar lenght is less than the size of `TextBox3.Text`

Which is the lenght of the field ? For example, if is `Varchar(5)` and `TextBox3.Text` is `"abcdef"` you can't insert the text because it will be truncated

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you the value in the textbox is [too big](http://aartemiou.blogspot.com.au/2009/02/string-or-binary-data-would-be.html) for the field/parameter

Check the definition of the parameter in the stored procedure, and the size of the field it is writing to.

Comment: damn, you win me for 3 seconds ! :P